# Show that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and $m(E)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

> Let Z $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with with $m(Z) = 0$.  Set $E=\left \{
> x^{2},  x \in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$. Suppose Z is bounded, that is,
> $Z\subseteq \left [ -n,n \right ]$ for some integer n. Show that $E$
> is Lebesgue measurable and $m(E)=0$.

My attempt:

$Z\subseteq \left [ -n,n \right ]$, then  $E\subseteq \left [ 0,n \right ]$. Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Suppose there exist some sequence of the intervals that: $Z\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k}, b_{k})$ and that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left | b_{k}-a_{k} \right |< \epsilon $.

Then $m^{2}(a_{k}^{2}, b_{k}^{2})=\left |b_{k}^{2} - a_{k}^{2} \right |=\left | b_{k}-a_{k} \right |\left | b_{k}+a_{k} \right |$.

From this point I do not know how to continue and even if it is correct.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @callculus is it really that simple?

Comment: @callculus and can you help?

Comment: @callculus can I delete it? It is embarrasing to post this question and it took 5 seconds for person to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a_k <x<b_k$ does not imply $a_k^{2} <x^{2} <b_k^{2}$. So your approach needs  a modification.

First note that by considering $(a_k,b_k) \cap (-n-1,n+1)$ (which is also an open integral we may suppose $|a_k|\leq n+1$ and $|b_k|\leq n+1$ for all $n$. Now $\{x^{2}: a_k <x<b_k\}$ is contained in

a) $(a_k^{2},b_k^{2})$ if $a_k \geq 0$

b) $(b_k^{2},a_k^{2})$ if $b_k \leq 0$ and

c)$(-\frac {\epsilon} {2^{k}},b_k^{2})$ if $a_k <0<b_k$.

Finally use the fact that $|a_k+b_k| |a_k-b_k| \leq 2(n+1) |a_k-b_k|$.

Now I believe you can put these together to complete the proof.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I have a problem to verify the c) case, can you help?

Comment: @Peter There was  a typo. I have corrected it. You may also note that $b_k <b_k-a_k$ so $b_k^{2}<(2n+1) (b_k-a_k)$ and $\sum \epsilon /2^{k} =\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much